# Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.22000.2360, timestamp: 0xe85aa406 Exception code: 0xc000027b

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin.forms, dll, uwp

I need some help, please.

I have a sideloaded application that when compiling in release mode is not opening on some machines (on some it opens normally).

If the application is started via Visual Studio (debug) it starts normally. Otherwise, via installation (Appx Add-AppPackage -Path...), it starts the screen and after a few seconds it closes.

When consulting eventvwr, this is the error message presented:

> Faulting application name: Application.exe.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, timestamp: 0x6508a68b
> Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.22000.2360, timestamp: 0xe85aa406
> Exception code: 0xc000027b
> Fault offset: 0x000000000083fe10
> Faulting process ID: 0x4728
> Failed application start time: 0x01d9eb2835b38fd4
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Application_X.X.XXX.X_x64__gnw0466hkgph6\Application.exe.exe
> Failing module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
> Report ID: e1c51326-591a-4289-bbb2-ac4905408da5
> Full name of the failing package: Application_X.X.XXX.X_x64__gnw0466hkgph6
> Application ID relative to the failed package: App

I generated a crash dump and this was the information, but I couldn't understand the error:

```
KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1
Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
Value: 10421
Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
Value: 14294
Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
Value: 0
Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
Value: 1
Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
Value: 0
Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
Value: 5234
Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
Value: 1343621
Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
Value: 620
Key  : Failure.Bucket
Value: STOWED_EXCEPTION_c000027b_Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!DirectUI::ErrorHelper::ProcessUnhandledError
Key  : Failure.Hash
Value: {a9671108-8db7-dad0-960d-26b0c425ea59}
Key  : Timeline.OS.Boot.DeltaSec
Value: 9820
Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
Value: 2
Key  : WER.OS.Branch
Value: co_release
Key  : WER.OS.Version
Value: 10.0.22000.1
Key  : WER.Process.Version
Value: 1.0.0.2

FILE_IN_CAB:  Application.exe.14072.dmp
NTGLOBALFLAG:  0
PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0
PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0
APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=0000000e5edfd4f0 rbx=0000000e5edfdad0 rcx=0000000e5edfd4f0
rdx=0000000e5edfd9a0 rsi=00007ffe50790401 rdi=0000000e5edfd4f0
rip=00007ffe4e2bd662 rsp=0000000e5edfd410 rbp=0000000000000001
r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000e5edfd960 r10=baac1f10365eb170
r11=0000000e5edfdad0 r12=ffffffffffffffff r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000002 r15=0000000000000004
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000200
KERNELBASE!RaiseFailFastException+0x152:
00007ffe`4e2bd662 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ffe410efe10 (Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ErrorHelper::ProcessUnhandledError+0x00000000000000f4)
ExceptionCode: c000027b
ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 2
Parameter[0]: 0000020726643280
Parameter[1]: 0000000000000004

PROCESS_NAME:  Application.exe
ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000027b - Ocorreu uma exce  o interna de aplicativo.
EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c000027b
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000020726643280
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000004

STACK_TEXT:  
0000000e`5edfd410 00007ffe`50870939     : 00000207`24b32738 00007ffe`50790401 00000207`24b32738 00000000`000036f8 : KERNELBASE!RaiseFailFastException+0x152
0000000e`5edfd9f0 00007ffe`410efe10     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000003 00000207`26604fc0 00000000`00000001 : combase!RoFailFastWithErrorContextInternal2+0x4d9
0000000e`5edfdc60 00007ffe`410efa2c     : 00000000`00000000 0000000e`5edfdd00 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000003 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ErrorHelper::ProcessUnhandledError+0xf4
0000000e`5edfdca0 00007ffe`410ef8b3     : 00007ffe`407cc2d0 0000000e`5edfde00 0000000e`00000000 00000207`266474d0 :
!DirectUI::FinalUnhandledErrorDetectedRegistration::OnFinalUnhandledErrorDetected+0xbc
0000000e`5edfdd20 00007ffe`40703324     : 00007ffe`4e9f0060 00000207`26647430 00000000`00000000 00000207`26660740 : Windows_UI_Xaml!Microsoft::WRL::Details::DelegateArgTraits<long (__cdecl Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler_impl<Windows::Foundation::Internal::AggregateType<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs *,Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::IUnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs *> >::*)(IInspectable *,Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::IUnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs *)>::DelegateInvokeHelper<Microsoft::WRL::Implements<Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<2>,Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs *>,Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase>,<lambda_fa46ac39691f4ca87fe78d9a3f2f4de1>,-1,IInspectable *,Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::IUnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs *>::Invoke+0x23
0000000e`5edfdd50 00007ffe`40703384     : 00000207`0629f960 00000207`26647430 0000000e`5edfde10 00000000`00000048 : twinapi_appcore!Windows::Internal::Details::GitInvokeHelper<Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64>,Windows::Internal::GitPtr,2>::Invoke+0x64
0000000e`5edfdd80 00007ffe`406f2d66     : 00000000`00000000 00007ffe`405f82ca 00000000`00000000 00000207`266474d0 :
!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorInvokeHelper::Invoke+0x24
0000000e`5edfddb0 00007ffe`4065bb74     : 00000207`0626b6b0 0000000e`5edfde60 00000000`00000000 00000207`0626b6b0 : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::InvokeTraits<2>::InvokeDelegates<<lambda_e478ebca019219710ec18bdfd8216607>,Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64> >+0x62
0000000e`5edfddf0 00007ffe`4065baed     : 00000207`0626b6b0 00000207`06273578 0000000e`5edfdeb0 00000000`00000000 : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::EventSource<Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64>,Microsoft::WRL::InvokeModeOptions<2> >::DoInvoke<<lambda_e478ebca019219710ec18bdfd8216607> >+0x78
0000000e`5edfde30 00007ffe`4065ba59     : 00000000`00000000 00000207`06273578 00000207`26647430 00000207`24b32738 : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::EventSource<Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64>,Microsoft::WRL::InvokeModeOptions<2> >::InvokeAll<std::nullptr_t,Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs * __ptr64>+0x29
0000000e`5edfde80 00007ffe`4065c807     : 00000000`00000000 00000207`24b32738 00000000`00000000 00000207`26647430 : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::ForwardLocalError+0x79
0000000e`5edfded0 00007ffe`5086f384     : 00000000`00000000 00000207`24b32738 00000207`06273540 00000000`00000001 : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationFactory::ForwardLocalError+0x77
0000000e`5edfdf10 00007ffe`5087112d     : 00007ffe`507904c0 00007ffe`507904c0 00000207`22162630 00007ffe`5070c2c2 : combase!CallErrorForwarder+0x150
0000000e`5edfdfa0 00007ffe`405f999e     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`80004005 00000000`80004005 00000000`00000000 : combase!RoReportFailedDelegate+0x24d
0000000e`5edfe030 00007ffe`405f9833     : 00000207`221626c0 00000207`24b32738 00000096`0000005a 00000207`221626c0 : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::InvokeTraits<-2>::InvokeDelegates<<lambda_b318c533f770df7f86e24469dce60a5b>,Windows::Foundation::ITypedEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView * __ptr64,Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation::IActivatedEventArgs * __ptr64> >+0x14a
0000000e`5edfe0a0 00007ffe`405f93d7     : 00000207`221626c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::EventSource<Windows::Foundation::ITypedEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView * __ptr64,Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation::IActivatedEventArgs * __ptr64>,Microsoft::WRL::InvokeModeOptions<-2> >::DoInvoke<<lambda_b318c533f770df7f86e24469dce60a5b> >+0x87
0000000e`5edfe100 00007ffe`4f3b5843     : 00000207`0627b178 00000000`00000003 00000207`06299800 00007ffe`4f3b57f6 : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Activate+0x5c7
0000000e`5edfe270 00007ffe`4f41be4c     : 0000000e`5edfe730 00007ffe`3806b828 00000207`06291e60 00000207`24ac87d0 : rpcrt4!Invoke+0x73
0000000e`5edfe2d0 00007ffe`4f37f4e2     : 0000000e`5edfe990 0000000e`5edfe978 0000000e`5edfe978 00007ffe`5070a055 : rpcrt4!Ndr64StubWorker+0xb7c
0000000e`5edfe970 00007ffe`5070888b     : 00000000`00000000 0000000e`5edfeba0 00007ffe`3806d910 00000207`0629e650 : rpcrt4!NdrStubCall3+0xd2
0000000e`5edfe9d0 00007ffe`4f3955c5     : 00000000`00000001 00000207`0629e650 00000207`221abed0 00007ffe`4727b5b0 : combase!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke+0x8b
0000000e`5edfea10 00007ffe`5070007d     : 00000207`221abed0 00000000`00000000 00002b83`f2480e9a 00000000`0000003c : rpcrt4!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke+0x45
0000000e`5edfea40 00007ffe`506ffe17     : 0000000e`5edff0e0 0000000e`5edfeb30 0000000e`5edfeae8 00000207`221b84a0 : combase!ObjectMethodExceptionHandlingAction<<lambda_c9f3956a20c9da92a64affc24fdd69ec> >+0x4d
0000000e`5edfeaa0 00007ffe`5070ce48     : 0000000e`5edfec58 00007ffe`5070a055 00000207`0626e478 00007ffe`3806b720 : combase!DefaultStubInvoke+0x257
0000000e`5edfebf0 00007ffe`5068d14b     : 00007ffe`3806d8a8 00007ffe`5070888b 00000000`00000000 0000000e`5edfee10 : combase!SyncServerCall::StubInvoke+0x38
0000000e`5edfec30 00007ffe`506d6a61     : 00000207`24ac87d0 0000000e`5edff364 00000207`221abed0 00007ffe`506d6ab8 : combase!ServerCall::ContextInvoke+0x46b
0000000e`5edfef10 00007ffe`506d6965     : 00000207`220e5770 0000000e`5edff011 00000000`00000000 00000207`24ac87d0 : combase!DefaultInvokeInApartment+0xc1
0000000e`5edfef60 00007ffe`50698f73     : 00007ffe`00000060 00000207`24ac8740 0000000e`5edff0c0 00000207`0627a730 : combase!ASTAInvokeInApartment+0x85
0000000e`5edff060 00007ffe`50677f25     : 00000207`24ac8740 00000000`00000000 d0908070`5edff488 00000207`221105f0 : combase!ComInvokeWithLockAndIPID+0xa13
0000000e`5edff350 00007ffe`50676035     : 0000000e`5edff860 00000207`062177d0 00000207`220e5770 00000000`00000002 : combase!ThreadDispatch+0x3d5
0000000e`5edff460 00007ffe`5067a3fa     : 00000000`00000000 0000000e`5edff5b0 00000207`062177d0 00000000`00000000 : combase!ModernSTAState::HandleMessage+0x55
0000000e`5edff4b0 00007ffe`50679d40     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000060 00000000`80000001 00000207`0627a730 : combase!ModernSTAWaitContext::Wait+0x632
0000000e`5edff7a0 00007ffe`41b53ba9     : 00000000`00000000 00007ffe`00000000 00000000`000002fc 00000207`06305d20 : combase!CoMsgWaitInProcessEvents+0xd0
0000000e`5edff800 00007ffe`41b53a07     : 0000000e`5edffa59 00000207`06305d58 0000000e`5edff980 00007ffe`40608ec9 : Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessagesInternal+0x139
0000000e`5edff910 00007ffe`405f8c12     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`80004005 00000207`06274a30 00007ffe`40667878 : Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages+0x37
0000000e`5edff940 00007ffe`405f8b38     : 00000207`06273540 00000207`06305d58 00000207`06305d20 00000000`00000000 : twinapi_appcore!Event::WaitAndProcessEvents+0x96
0000000e`5edff970 00007ffe`40666ef5     : 00000207`06274a30 00000207`06273540 00000207`06274a30 00000000`00000000 : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationViewAgileContainer::WaitForViewReady+0x40
0000000e`5edff9b0 00007ffe`50be4e9f     : 00000207`06274a30 00000000`00000000 00000207`06273540 00000000`00000000 : twinapi_appcore!<lambda_42789f15e44e28e8f1176a4d3f326103>::operator()+0x81
0000000e`5edff9e0 00007ffe`502c53e0     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : SHCore!_WrapperThreadProc+0x10f
0000000e`5edffac0 00007ffe`50ce485b     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x10
0000000e`5edffaf0 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x2b

STACK_COMMAND:  ~8s; .ecxr ; kb
FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE:  onecoreuap\windows\dxaml\xcp\dxaml\lib\errorhelper.cpp
FAULTING_SOURCE_FILE:  onecoreuap\windows\dxaml\xcp\dxaml\lib\errorhelper.cpp
FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE_NUMBER:  616
FAULTING_SOURCE_CODE:  No source found for 'onecoreuap\windows\dxaml\xcp\dxaml\lib\errorhelper.cpp'
SYMBOL_NAME:  Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ErrorHelper::ProcessUnhandledError+f4
MODULE_NAME: Windows_UI_Xaml
IMAGE_NAME:  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  STOWED_EXCEPTION_c000027b_Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!DirectUI::ErrorHelper::ProcessUnhandledError
OS_VERSION:  10.0.22000.1
BUILDLAB_STR:  co_release
OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64
OSNAME:  Windows 10
IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.22000.2360
FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {a9671108-8db7-dad0-960d-26b0c425ea59}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

---

Já tentei alguns passos, mas nenhum deram certo:

- Run wsreset.exe
- Delete windows store cache via regedit
- Restore windows store
- Run the command Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
- Run the command $manifest = (Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsStore).InstallLocation + '\AppxManifest.xml' ; Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $manifest
- Confirmed that the DLL Windows.UI.Xaml.dll is allowed for all applications
- Performed installation test of the same application on other machines
- Perform all pending Windows Update updates

Haven't tried yet

- Create a new user
- Format the machine

As it is a corporate machine, these processes are more bureaucratic to carry out, which is why they have not yet been tried.

Below are the settings of one of the machines that presents the error:

> Processor: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7/ RAM: 32.0GB/ Windows 11 PRO - 21H2 - Build 22000.2416 - 64Bits

Comment: If you create a blank UWP project, can the same problem be reproduced? What do the machines in question have in common?

Comment: We haven't tested the blank application yet.
The machines that have the problem, in common, are relatively new. They all have the same settings described.
We try to compare the version of the Windows.UI.XAML.dll DLL from a working machine to a non-working machine and both are at the same version.

Comment: 0xc000027b is Stowed Exception and probably the worst thing to debug...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/inside/c000027b